# Insert to hive table not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, mapper, reducers

I am having straight forward hive table
[image]

when I insert into this table I get the following error.
[image]

The kill command is being executed and the number of mappers and reducers are 0.

## Update

I have used insert into table dept values('1','HR');
even then I got similar error as below
[image]

and I have checked the log of the job which is as below

[image]
Am I missing anything in the configuration of hive. Need help...
Thanks

Comment: After adding below to my classpath, Error got solved

Answer (score 0):

This is not the write command

```
INSERT INTO TABLE dept
VALUES ('1', 'HR'), ('2', 'IT');
```

Use table before table name and it will work

**Updated as the question is updaed:**

Set

> YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME instead of HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

in env setup file which will be something liek this.

> export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop export
>   HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
>   export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME export
>   HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME export
>   HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native" export
>   HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native

Comment: Thanks, 
I found this error "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster" in the logs as said above

Comment: Set YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME instead of HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME in env setup file which will be something liek this. export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native

Comment: Tried adding these to yarn-env.sh even then didn't work